# LoadError: cannot load such file -- in my custom gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I created a gem and installed it on my system. The gem has 2 rb files, Myfile.rb and file_two.rb, one requires another, both are in lib folder. When I'm trying to load it in irb like require 'Myfile', I get an error
- LoadError: cannot load such file -- /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/Myfile-0.1.0/lib/file_two

In gem folder I see only 1 file. I believe the problem is in the following snippet of gemspec:

```
  spec.files         = Dir['Rakefile', '{bin,lib}/**/*',
                       'README*', 'LICENSE*'] & `git ls-files -z`.split("\0")
  spec.bindir        = "exe"
  spec.executables   = spec.files.grep(%r{^exe/}) { |f| File.basename(f) }
  spec.require_paths = ["lib"]
```

Please, advice how to rewrite it correctly, so both my files get into gem package.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to show the error message. We can't tell what that error is.

Comment: Did you build the gem?

Comment: Sorry, forgot the message - LoadError: cannot load such file -- /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/Myfile-0.1.0/lib/file_two. And yes, I built the gem and installed it on my system

Comment: Have you added `file_two.rb` to git? Your `gemspec` uses `git ls-files` to only include those files tracked by git, so if you haven’t committed the file it won’t be included in the built Gem.